# Statistical Measure for Bidirectional Relationships

Tags: descriptive-statistics, contingency-tables, graph-theory, correspondence-analysis

I have a karma website where you can create a topic and someone can upvote the topic once.

People who receive upvotes from another individual tend to upvote topics from the other individual.

What is a good statistical measure for determining directional relationships between users who might be giving each other upvotes.

I have access to the data for each user and want to say lay out a table with a score for each pair of users measuring upvote buddies.

Answer (score 1):

Let the users be indexed by $i=1,\dotsc,N$.  Make a square contingency table $C=(c_{ij})$ where $c_{ij}=\text{number of times $i$ upvoted $j$}$.  Since presumably a user cannot upvote himself this table would have zeros along the diagonal.

Now from this table various descriptives can be calculated:

1. $c_{\cdot \cdot}=\sum_i\sum_j c_{ij}$ the total number of votes
2. $c_{\cdot j}= \sum_i c_{ij}$ total number of votes on user $j$
3. $c_{i \cdot}$ is total number of votes from user $i$
4. $\frac{c_{ij}}{c_{i\cdot}}$ fraction of $i$'s votes given to $j$
5. ...

You are asking specifically about *directional relationships* it is not entirely clear what that is. If you are interested in pairs of users $(i,j)$ where $i$ is "giving" (much) more than "receiving", you could look at maybe $\frac{c_{ij}}{c_{ji}}$, or the corresponding ratio of proportions.  Other interpretations could probably also be given, using the counts in $C$.

If you want to go deeper, you could represent the table as a *graph* and look for *community detection* in graphs. Or you could look for models for square contingency tables. Or correspondence analysis for square tables could be interesting. If you express interest in some of these I could write some more on that.